# Font size too big in Opera

Tags: css, opera

I have a text item on a web page that appears too large in opera browsers. Is there a way to edit text size and other aspects of the css for only opera?

Comment: Which browser(s) does the text item appear correct in? Is it only that specific item or other/all text on the same page? Could you perhaps provide a link or http://jsfiddle.net/ with the code?

Comment: The text appears correct in Firefox, Google Chrome, and IE 9 + 8 (haven't tested the others yet). Its plain text, but it appears bigger on Opera. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taRUZ/)

Comment: Which metric are you using for the font-size? Try using the `em`

Comment: The text appears the same for me in Opera (v11.10 on Windows) as it does in Firefox. Look at the bottom right of your Opera browser's window. Is zoom set to anything other than `View (100%)`? ;-)

Comment: No the view is set to 100%. I think the width is off in opera, which is what is making the text not match up correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out this link (scroll down to the part about Opera) 
[Here](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/)

(I never knew this but...) apparently you can use:

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:10000), not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

.operaSpecificStuff { }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Opera has a bug in font size defined by em or %. Just reset the font size like this:

```
body { font-size: 16px;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Opera doesn't allow for font-sizes smaller than 10px – which results in having bigger fonts on small texts in Opera only. This is intended by design as this setting can be changed by the user only.

See the following thread: http://forums.devshed.com/css-help-116/force-opera-to-use-font-size-less-than-10px-or-763589.html